# Iptables - Remove filtered ports and close them

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, port

Here's the result of `nmap` command on my dedicated server from my home linux pc :

```
Not shown: 980 closed ports
PORT      STATE    SERVICE
20/tcp    filtered ftp-data
21/tcp    filtered ftp
22/tcp    open     ssh
53/tcp    filtered domain
80/tcp    open     http
81/tcp    filtered hosts2-ns
110/tcp   filtered pop3
135/tcp   filtered msrpc
139/tcp   filtered netbios-ssn
143/tcp   filtered imap
443/tcp   open     https
445/tcp   filtered microsoft-ds
587/tcp   filtered submission
993/tcp   filtered imaps
995/tcp   filtered pop3s
3306/tcp  filtered mysql
8080/tcp  filtered http-proxy
8081/tcp  filtered blackice-icecap
8443/tcp  filtered https-alt
40193/tcp filtered unknown

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 2.34 seconds
```

Right now, I have the following rules on this dedicated server :

```
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0] 
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0] 
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0] 
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

Actually, I want to close all ports except 22, 80 and 443. But I don't know how to close all the ports appearing "filtered" with `nmap` command (on the results list above).

If someone could give me help to resolve this issue,

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am not sure if you care but filtered ports are better than closed ports. Filtered in the `nmap` parlance means that there is no response from the server. Part of using the firewall is to use it to mask as much of the server from the Internet as possible. Filtered ports are one good way to do that.

Comment: ok, I found out actually that my dedicated server (vps) has a front firewall which indicates these filtered ports. From what I have understood and for more security, I have also applied my own iptables rules for the server itself (i.e close all ports except the 22, 80 and 443 ports).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the link below you should end your rules with

```
-j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
```

instead of

```
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

See http://diaryproducts.net/about/operating_systems/unix/nmap_port_scanner_iptables_firewall

Then the port will look like there is no service running on it, as tcp-reset is the response to an unused port.

But you say you have another firewall in front, so the question is moo, as Joey puts it ;-)

Comment: when you say "you should end your rules", what does it mean ? Should I set for example with port 22 : -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j  REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset ?? But I want to ACCEPT input ssh, not REJECT it.

Comment: It should be as the last catch-all lines, instead of your last two. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your rules:

```
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

with

```
-A INPUT -j DROP
-A FORWARD -j DROP
```

REJECT mostly used in local network and if your server is looking to the internet I can suggest using DROP instead.

Take a look [here](https://serversuit.com/community/technical-tips/view/easy-setup-of-iptables-on-your-new-linux-server.html) for more iptables examples may help too.